# How to locate the issue with the following error message from petalinux boot command?

Tags: embedded-linux, petalinux

When I give the following command in my petalinux project :
petalinux-boot --jtag --fpga --bitstream ../system.bit --u-boot

I get the following error. When I searched the internet I could not find any answer:

```
rlwrap: warning: your $TERM is 'xterm-256color' but rlwrap couldn't find it in the terminfo database. Expect some problems.: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Memory read error at 0xF8007080. MMU section translation fault                         
    invoked from within
"::tcf::eval -progress {apply {{msg} {puts $msg}}} {tcf_send_command tcfchan#0 Memory get siiii {Bea{o{msg o{} A}}} {JTAG-jsn-DLC10-00001c72991001-4ba00477-0.0 4160778368 4 4 7}}"
    (procedure "::tcf::send_command" line 4)
    invoked from within
"::tcf::send_command $chan Memory get "siiii" "Bea{o{msg o{} A}}" [list $ctx $start_addr $size $nbytes $mode]"
    (procedure "mrd" line 87)
    invoked from within
"mrd 0xF8007080"
    (procedure "ps_version" line 2)
    invoked from within
"ps_version"
    (procedure "ps7_post_config" line 8)
    invoked from within
"ps7_post_config"
    (file "/tmp/tmp.8jPVijmAkY" line 12)
INFO: The XSDB log is as follows
```

I tried to resolve the issue by seaerching the Zynq 7000 board documentation I tried to boot linux on AVNET board. There I find the following:
"The MMU might not find a global mapping or a mapping for the currently selected ASID with a matching non-secure TLB ID (NSTID) for the virtual address in the TLB. In this case, the hardware does a translation table walk if the translation table walk is enabled by the PD0 or PD1 bit in the TTB Control register. If translation table walks are disabled, the processor returns a section translation fault".

Further search leads to the link https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/52033?language=en_US

Not sure it is helpful.
I get the same error if I give the command petalinux-boot --jtag --kernel --hw_server-url tcp:127.0.0.1:3121. Does it help to solve the issue?

Edit: I tried to use XSCT and when I gave the command

```
 xsct% dow "../zynq_fsbl.elf"
```

I get

```
 : Memory write error at0x0. MMU section translation fault.
```

Does it help to reolve the issue?

I have done the booting command several times. It appears that MMU must be disabled to download FSBL is this correct?

Comment: According to the text of the error message, there is no readable memory at 0xF8007080... Please [edit] your question and add relevant information.

Comment: May I ask when do you get no readable memory at a location? What exactly does it mean? Alternative, how to find the additional information required.

Comment: The error message gives you a hint: a MMU defines which ranges are accessible for read, write, and/or execute. You need to [edit] your question to provide enough information for us to help you, especially your level of experience. But according to your questions, I'm afraid that the format of this site will not help you. This is not a forum but a Q&A site. Visit the websites of your system and petalinux and read...

Comment: I am working on embedded linux for few weeks now. I have no experience on working with Linux or embedded system. So I do not know "who" is generating the error? I searched the error message "MMU section translation fault" in documentation of Petalinux as I was expecting petalinux is generating but there is no clue.

Comment: The followingI have found the closest in the documentation of zynq 7000:  The MMU might not find a global mapping or a mapping for the currently selected ASID
with a matching non-secure TLB ID (NSTID) for the virtual address in the TLB. In this case,
the hardware does a translation table walk if the translation table walk is enabled by the
PD0 or PD1 bit in the TTB Control register. If translation table walks are disabled, the
processor returns a section translation fault.

Comment: Please add these relevant information to your question by [edit]ing it. Don't forget to add the details of your target system, and anything else to reproduce, too. This is not a forum, comments are not searched for information.

Comment: I have added few additional information, is it possible to track the cause of error? By the way how do I know if the linux is already there in the target board Avnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writting as answer as it might help someone else in future. The problem was that the board was already running something and therefore when we try to boot again, it gave MMU translation error. This can happen when one tries to boot several times. The solution is to power off the board, run minicom or some other serial port connection software and then give boot command.